# retrieve text from textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have

```
 if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.lbl.text=@"abc";
        cell.txtField.placeholder=@"abc"
        cell.txtField.tag=104;
    delegate.copyNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cell.txtField text]];
    } else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        cell.lbl.text=@"home";
        cell.txtField.placeholder=@"xyz";
        cell.txtField.tag=105;    
    }
```

I am trying to retrieve the text which is in textfield, at row 0 and row 1.

i am trying to retrieve text on the textfield on the basis of tag.
How can i retrieve text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can retrive your textfield like this and when you got your required textfield ,then get text.

```
    UITableViewCell *myCell = (UITableViewCell *)[*yourTableViewName* cellForRowAtIndexPath:*passindexPath*]];
    UITextField *mytextFiled = (UITextField *)[myCell viewWithTag:104];
```

Answer (score 0):

the direct answer to your question is to use `viewWithTag`. In your example, `[cell viewWithTag:105]` will give you the text field. That said, your example has other issues.

First, if you can access the cell and the cell has a `txtField` property than you don't need the tag. Just use `cell.txtField` when you have the cell. Tags are typically used when you don't have a property holding a reference to the view you need. If you can't access the cell, the tag won't help you.

Second, you shouldn't add subviews directly to the cell. Instead you should add them to the cells contentView. The docs explain how to create a custom `UITableViewCell` fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *textValue=((UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:104]).text;
```

You do like this,

```
 UITextField *urtextFiled = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:104];
NSString *textValue=[urtextFiled text];
```

Comment: property 'text' not found on object of type "UIView". this is the error coming out.

Answer (score 0):

In which method you are trying to retrieve the text? I think you have to set delegate for your textfield and retrieve the text from this delegate method -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField